# Converting from an exact number of seconds to DateTime

Tags: c#

I have got a total number of seconds. Now I need to print those seconds to a d:HH:mm:ss format.

I tried the following:

```
double totalSeconds = filteredPictures + totalFilterTime + totalUploadTime;
string output = totalSeconds.ToString($"{total:dd.HH:mm:ss}");
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

What am I doing that's not quite right?

Comment: Well, what do you expect and what do you get instead?

Comment: try `new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, totalSeconds)` insstead of just `totalSeconds`. Note that you probably want a TimeSpan, not a DateTime. They are different things.

Comment: 0:06:37:07 - something like that and I get dd110220HH:mm:ss

Comment: That is because `totalSeconds` is a double (ie number). You can't format it (your ToString) as a date/time. Also your format string is not correct even if you did have the correct type.

Comment: Well then how do I do it?

Comment: Read the comments, it is pretty much spelled out for you.

Answer (score 3):

If you convert your total number of seconds to a `TimeSpan` using something like the following:

```
var timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(totalSeconds);
```

You can then print the `TimeSpan` using [standard TimeSpan format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-timespan-format-strings)